# Qt - QFile - How to read only first word in every line

Tags: qt, cpu-word, fstream, qfile

How can I read only first word in every line in a text file while using QFile in Qt?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to read whole lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
    QFile ifile("in.txt");
    QString text = txStream.readLine();
    QStringList splitline = text.split(" ");
    QFile ofile("out.txt");
    ofile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);

     QTextStream out(&ofile);

     // join QStringList by "\n" to write each single word in an own line
     out << splitline.join("\n");

     ofile.close();
```

Comment: Ok, but how to get first word from that line?

Comment: do you have headers in your file?

Comment: No i dont. Why do you ask?

Comment: What i have is lines of text and i want to get first word of every line.